# PhoneGap Open an external link in my application with Chrome that loads in the app

Tags: android, cordova, chromium, window.open, inappbrowser

I'm developing a PhoneGap application using the Durandal framework, which loads an external link when the deviceready event is triggered. I'd like to open Chrome since the website I'm linking to needs Chrome's features to work with WebAudio. Also, performance is overall better with Chrome. I'm able to load the link with the Chrome browser using the following code, but what I would like to do is load a Chrome browser within the application itself to give the appearance of a native application. The Cordova WebView (_self) and InAppBrowser's WebView (_blank) just aren't meeting my needs for this application. Opening Chrome works fine using the system default (_system), but opening the Chrome browser outside the app provides a pretty poor user experience since they see that it is just opening an external link and leaving the phonegap application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/durandal/css/durandal.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

    function onLoad(){

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", 

        onDeviceReady,

        false);

    }


    function onDeviceReady() {
            window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "location=no");
     }


</script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div id="applicationHost"></div>
    <script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using PhoneGap 3.5.0 with an HTC One running 4.4.2. Using the InAppBrowser plugin with PhoneGap.

```
 Options I'm considering:
 1) Developing a plugin like InAppBrowser to open Chrome in my application, is it possible? 
 How difficult/time consuming would that be?
 2) Ship the application with Chrome, or minified version of Chrome, 
 that opens the external link in my application?
```

Any suggestions, comments, or additions to my code above would be much appreciated. Thanks!